# How to upsert records with Node.js to MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I need to upsert more records to a collection with one `Node.js` web service. I would call it `ModifyRecordsOperation`. It should parse an array of `collectionName`, `recordType`, `recordName`, and nested `array` of field names and values. I guess I have to parse the request body, am I right? Should I use `JSON.parse` module?

Do you know any easy and compact solution? I thought to use MongoDB as a storage.

I am newbie at Node.js. I thought I will implement a POST route, parse the body with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), loop records, and upsert with [db.collection.update()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/). Do you know any more compact solution?

```
app.post('/ModifyRecordsOperation', function(req, res) {

  var body = JSON.parse(req.body)
  for(var record in body) {

    var recordName = record['recordName'];
    var recordType = record['recordType'];

    console.log(' recordName: 'recordName + " recordType: " + recordType);
  }
};
```

Comment: You can possibly call them mean names or not treat them with respect. did you mean "upsert"? But in general you need to add a lot more than this. This reads as "write my code for me, because I have not bothered to try". Make some effort. I have a mind to close something with an empty route and no code attempt whatsoever.

Comment: Going from all the revisions In the last 10 minutes I'm guessing your engilsh is not great. That's not a problem, but your lack of effort in your question is. If you have someone to help you translate then get them to do so please. Yout need to "read more reference documentation". All of these basics are documented elsewhere of how to accesss, and find / modify / create.